# Breaking up Drupal's node url

Tags: php, url, variables, drupal-6

I would like to break up the url variable in Drupal 6 so I can place a directory name between the $base_url and the rest of the path. Any ideas as to how I could do this?

Thanks,
Jane

Answer (score 0):

Well, it sounds like you already know the the $base_url, so the part you need is the internal path, which you can retrieve with `$path = arg();`.

However, I don't know what you hope to accomplish by doing this.  Suppose you have a drupal URL like this:

`http://www.example.com/node/76`

That's actually an alias for THIS url:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?q=node/76`

The node/76 part is the internal drupal path, and the .htaccess file in the root folder cuts out the index.php?q= bit for a cleaner url.

So if you construct an URL like this:

`http://www.example.com/directory/node/76`

It will actually be pointing at:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?q=directory/node/76`

Which will then fail, because Drupal will try to treat directory/node/76 as an internal Drupal path, and not find it -- so you'll get a 404 error.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So let's say, I have the following url: http://www.example.com/about/history, I want to add a directory name between http://www.example.com/ and about/history to end up with something like http://www.example.com/content/about/history, so I know I could write something like $base_url/content/... but then is there an existing variable for the remainder of the url? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the end goal here? I could give you a better answer if I had a clearer idea of what you're trying to accomplish. For example, how many pages do you need to alter in this way? Are you working with template.php?  Or altering a module?  Or working through the administrative interface? If you have a code snippet you could show me, that would be helpful too (edit original question for that, please).

Comment: I would like to point users to a print-friendly version of the page. The print-friendly version would be placed in an alternate directory, hence the need to add a directory name to the path. Alternatively, I could just use an existing print-friendly module, but to position it the way I want to, my understanding is that I would need to use the $node instead of the $content to fully customize how the content appears on the page. And, well, that is something I have yet to master! :-)

Comment: @Jane You're right that there are existing modules for this, namely http://drupal.org/project/print, which generates urls like `example.com/print/42` (42 = node ID). What is it about the appearance of the content on the page that you want to customize? Ordinarily, that would be handled by copying `print.tpl.php` from modules/print to your theme directory and editing it, without any particular need to alter underlying variables directly. For modifying the print-friendly links themselves, override `theme_print_format_link()` with your own theme function.

Comment: Yes I actually thought of going with the print module you mention, it certainly works quite nicely... the only thing is I would like to place it outside of the $content area in a box with other elements one would typically find such as sharing on social media sites, etc. Otherwise, is there a way I can place my other custom elements with print inside the $content area? Thanks so much for your help!